# Why is pinmux mentioned outside ocp in dts file?

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, device-tree

In the file https://git.ti.com/ti-linux-kernel/ti-linux-kernel/blobs/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/am33xx.dtsi which is the dtsi file for the am33xx processor I find that pinmux memory map for the control module registers is mentioned outside the OCP bus entry as shown below

```
am33xx_pinmux: pinmux@44e10800 {
    compatible = "pinctrl-single";
    reg = <0x44e10800 0x0238>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    pinctrl-single,register-width = <32>;
    pinctrl-single,function-mask = <0x7f>;
};
```

Why is this exactly mentioned outside the OCP when all other devices are inside?